# Use spring security in jsf project

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I want to use spring security in my jsf project but with minimal xml configuration use. But when I use annottaion based configuration as follows :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("123456").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();

}
}
```

I get this error :

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Custom context class [com.spring.SecurityConfig] is not of type [org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext]
```

Should the security configuration class implement ConfigurableWebApplicationContext ? If yes how to do this ? If no what is the solution ?

According to the spring tutorial only 2 classes is required for spring security, one that I pasted above and the other is :

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
    AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
    super(SecurityConfig.class);
}
}
```

and my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>OnlineLibrary</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>com.spring.SecurityConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

I use these libraries for my project :
jsf 2.2

spring-security-3.2.4.RELEASE

and other required libraries for spring, an i run my project on tomcat 7.
thanks for your usefull answers.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you forgot to make a new class where you have to define :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And because you don't use spring mvc, may be this link could help you : 
http://laabidi-raissi.blogspot.fr/2013/07/jsf-2-spring-security-integration-with.html
He degines beans in an applicationContext.xml but you could have some hints to find the missing piece.

Comment: But I don't need Spring web mvc because I am using jsf. The only thing I want to do is to add spring security functionality to jsf project. And also the exception is about the SecurityConfig class that is said it should implement org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext interface.

Comment: Could you show your pom.xml and your main Configuration Class?

Comment: the web application context is something you need to load your spring beans in a webapp. My bad, if my solution isn't good. But the solution you search is "how to load my security config", so the way to search is probably in your web.xml, may be missing a listener or something like that. I complete my answer if i have more information